# Reliable bidirectional communication to a Linux process?

Tags: linux, process, communication

What is the reliable way of implementing bidirectional communication to a Linux process?

I see that [popen](http://linux.die.net/man/3/popen) does not seem to support "r" and "w" access at the same time... or at least that's what is implied:

`The type argument is a pointer to a null-terminated string which must be either 'r' for reading or 'w' for writing.`

(I am so missing Erlang at the moment)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Unix domain sockets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_domain_socket) are your friend.

> A Unix domain socket or IPC socket
>   (inter-process communication socket)
>   is a data communications endpoint that
>   is similar to an Internet socket, but
>   does not use a network protocol for
>   communication. It is used in POSIX
>   operating systems for inter-process
>   communication.

You reserve a name for your communications channel, such as `/myapp/ipc`, and then both processes open that address using a UNIX socket:

```
struct sockaddr_un local;
int len;

s = socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
local.sun_family = AF_UNIX;
strcpy(local.sun_path, "/myapp/ipc");
len = strlen(local.sun_path) + sizeof(local.sun_family);
bind(s, (struct sockaddr *)&local, len);
```

Now you can use `listen` or `connect` or whatever else in the socket family. It's a little bit of work, but is the best way to achieve IPC on Linux.

Since Erlang is just a nice language for specifying little servers (processes) that communicate over named pipes (processes), this model should feel comfortable to you.

Comment: ... so I would spawn a process and pass a reference to an opened & listening socket in the arguments?

Comment: Or use a named socket (see `mkfifo`). For bidirectional communication, you just need two of them...

Answer (score 2):

Good old TCP/IP connections have always worked well for me.

Comment: Unix domain sockets are much more efficient than TCP.

Comment: But TCP has the benefit of allowing your system to scale to more than 1 box. Fortunately, porting code from unix domain sockets to TCP is trivial.